# Updating relationship or other data via find

Tags: ember.js

**Edit: More generally, how can I call find() and have it do something with each item in the result set**

How do I update the members of a set relationship without breaking bindings? E.g. a model hasMany somethings, but initially load only the first 10, and then later I want to replace those with the next 10, etc, for pagination

I can call clear and add on the underlying OrderedSet, but that breaks bindings on my page, and everything just dissappears.

```
App.Category = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  type: DS.attr("string"),
  parent: DS.belongsTo('App.Category'),
  children: DS.hasMany('App.Category'),
  stories: DS.hasMany('App.Story'),

});

App.CategoryController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  page: 1,

  loadPage: function() {
    console.log(this.get('stories'))
    var s = App.Story.find({sid: this.get('id'), count: 12, page: this.get('page')})
    this.get('stories').clear()
    for (var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i) {
      this.get('stories').add(s[i])
    }
  },
  nextPage: function(event) {
    this.set('page', this.get('page') + 1)
    this.loadPage()

  },
  prevPage: function(events) {
    this.set('page', this.get('page') - 1)
    this.loadPage()
  },
  breadcrumb: function() {
    return ""
  }.property('parent'),
  sortProperties: ['created'],
  sortAscending: false,
  nextEnabled: function() {
    return true
  }.property('page'),
  prevEnabled: function() {
    if (this.get('page') > 1) {
      return true
    }
    return false
  }.property('page'),

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, ORMs do not provide for pagination of children within the parent object. The normal way to deal with this is to break out of the object model and maintain for yourself a parent object and separate pageable collection of children objects.  In other words, you have to break the bindings and then manage them yourself for the purposes of this page.

Comment: Ember isn't really an ORM though, and dataobjects are long lived.

Comment: The part of Ember you are asking about is an Object-Relational Mapper (ORM): it maps objects in memory to objects in a long-lived relational database and vice versa.  (Using object IDs to record hasMany relationships is what makes it relational.)  Ember's [ORM implementation](https://github.com/emberjs/data) is, at the moment, "a work in progress" and not production ready, so you should not expect it to have features that even mature ORM implementations do not have.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than binding to a single array that is emptied and repopulated when you change pages, I would suggest you do the following:

1. Store the current page index in the `page` property of your controller (done)
2. Store the desired number of items per query in the `count` property of your controller (done)
3. Create a computed property `pageContent` that depends on `page` and `count`. It should return a `find()` query with those parameters
4. As a bonus, have `pageContent` cache each query for performance

Your model and controller would look something like this:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string')
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    cache: [],
    counts: [5, 10, 20, 50],

    page: 0,
    count: 5,

    pageContent: function() {
        var page = this.get('page');
        var count = this.get('count');
        var key = this.keyFor(page, count);

        var cache = this.get('cache');
        if (!cache[key]) {
            // we don't have this pair of index and count cached,
            // so retrieve data from the api and cache it
            cache[key] = App.Post.find({page: page, count: count});
        }

        return cache[key];
    }.property('page', 'count'),

    // generates hash key for page and count pair
    keyFor: function(page, count) {
        return page + '-' + count;
    },

    // actions                                            
    next: function() {
        this.incrementProperty('page');
    },

    previous: function() {
        if(this.get('page') > 0) {
            this.decrementProperty('page');
        }
    }               
});
```

Now in your template, you bind to `pageContent`.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    {{#each pageContent}}
        <p>-{{title}}</p>
    {{/each}}

    <button {{action previous}}>Previous</button>
    <button {{action next}}>Next</button>
    <br/>

    {{view Ember.Select contentBinding="counts" selectionBinding="count"}}
    items per page
</script>
```

[Here's the whole thing running in a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmacleod/CwZCT/).